# How to change jQuery dialog html content after init?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a working dialog, and i want to change the content during the flow of the app, I mean to change the .html() property of the dialog...

I thought it was easy to do but i can't seem to do:

$dialog.dialog().html(**SOME CONTENT**);

How do I do that after I already have the dialog running?

My init code is:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html(SplitTable)
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        title: 'פיצול שולחן'});

    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

where is the ID in that? this is the what i understood i should do from the examples, didn't see any Id property...

p.s. **splitTable** is the content that i need to change during to program to **updatTable**...

10x

Comment: Why add $ in front of JavaScript variable?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure that the `$dialog` variable is in scope where you're wanting to change the content, then just a [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) call will work, like this:

```
$dialog.html(updatTable);
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ldktu/).

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#dialog ID').html('SOME CONTENT');
```

Comment: sorry, didn't get the id part, i'm posting my init code...10x